# jqGrid and Rx Reactive javascript extensions

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, reactive-extensions-js

I am trying to create an Observable of onSelectRow events in jqGrid
using the syntax below:

```
grid.jqGrid().toObservable("onSelectRow").Select(function (event) {
                 return alert($(event.target).val());
            });
```

Nothing seems to be happening. Most examples bind to simple events like click in documentation. I cannot find any complex implementation examples. How can this achieved?

Comment: First i dont know about toObservable, can you guide me to a link about it. Second, just a guess use grid.jqGrid instead of grid.jqGrid().

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/gg577611 Introducing RxJS - Reactive Extensions for JavaScript